# Issues with form displaying and make different links view on same page?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a few questions that I am not able to solve after researching. One question is why my form is not displaying. I have linked a JSfiddle demo further down this page. The primary question is on the left when you see the demo I have four different links. I want each link to display a different form or lets say anything I want within the confinement of the white space on the right hand side of the left navigation menu and under the header. I can't seem to find a way to possibly do this. If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/kU9uL/

HTML Code:

```
<html>

<head>

  <title>Our Cool Banking App</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>


<body>

  <div class="header">Our Really Cool Banking App</div>

  <div id="leftcolumn"> 
      <!-- Creating Buttons here -->
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#checking">Checking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#savings">Savings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#createaccount">Create Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#createloan">Create Loan</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="inputBox">Test</box> -->

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="Username"><br>
    <input type="number" name="Amount"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="accounttype" value="Checking"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="accounttype" value="Savings"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="bankaction" value="Deposit"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="bankaction" value="Withdraw"><br>
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 1265px;
  line-height:68px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);

  /* styles under are just for fun */
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-indent: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

/* making backgrounds compatible */  
.header {
  background: rgba(20,82,159,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(20,82,159,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,119,230,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#14529f', endColorstr='#0077e6', GradientType=0 );
}

#leftcolumn{
  float: center;
  width: 200px; /*Width of left column*/
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  color: white;
}

#leftcolumn {
  background: rgba(20,82,159,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(20,82,159,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,119,230,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(20,82,159,1) 0%, rgba(0,119,230,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#14529f', endColorstr='#0077e6', GradientType=0 );
}

#nav {
  color: white;
}

#nav ul {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#nav ul li { 
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin: 0px 0 40px 0;
}

a:link    {color:white;}
a:visited {color:white;}
a:active  {color:white;}
a:hover   {color:rgb(152,152,152);}


/*.inputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  line-height:400px;
  margin-top: -625px;
  margin-left: 450px;

  background: black;

  /* styles under are just for fun */
/*  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  text-indent: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}*/
```

Comment: `float: center` doesn't exist...

Comment: @tilix thanks! That solved the first issue

Answer (score 1):

After removing your `float: center`, the form appear on the right of your left nav:
http://jsfiddle.net/z5sYB/

Answer (score 0):

easy breezy.

```
 <nav class="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">tab 1</li>
            <li class="tab-link " data-tab="tab-2">tab 2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
       tab 2 content
    </div>


$('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    var tabId = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tabId).addClass('current');
});
```

I would assume you need something like
.tab-content {display: none}
.tab-content .current {display:block}

Sending from phone. Sorry for brevity. Don't forget to use jquery library and document ready.

Comment: What goes under the class of li? I am lost on that. From my understanding within the <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"> we can add whatever we want and it will populate to the right hand side of the left navigation and under the header?

Comment: Updated to include CSS for you.